# How to insert a buffer geometry into a new table using java?

Tags: java, postgresql

Here Geometry buffer = geom.buffer(5.00);

Thus buffer contains a data as polygon and the latitude and longitude of all the points in the 5km radius .

This line of code that I wrote isn't working . What is a better way to go about it ?

```
String query1 = " INSERT INTO  buffer(the_geom) " + buffer + ";";
```

So what should be the sql query ?

Answer (score 1):

insert into table_name values (column1, column2,...) values (column1Value, column2value,...)

Comment: Can you post the exception and your updated code? Also, if you have access to a console that lets you enter the query manually you can use that to help you fine tune dynamic SQL.